# Letf align item name in itemize

Tags: itemize

I have an itemize with custom item names.

How do I left-align and right-pad the item names so that they start in line with normal text on the page and the item descriptions align with each other?

This is what I am currently working with:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[Array:]
Fixed size vector of other type-objects.\newline
All type-objects contained must be of the same type.
...
\item[BasicType:]
All scalar types of C (int, double, unsigned short, char\ldots).\newline
Represented as a fixed-size vector of bytes.
\end{itemize}
```

And this is how it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Maybe a table without borders would be better suited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time please give a minimal working sample.

I advise you to use the `description` environment which could be revised to get the desired output by the `enumitem` package. See the following MWS. By the way, it's better to delete the colons (`:`) after the label words.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
Some texts.
\begin{description}[leftmargin=7em, labelwidth=7em, labelsep=0em]
\item[Array:]
Fixed size vector of other type-objects.\newline
All type-objects contained must be of the same type.
...
\item[BasicType:]
All scalar types of C (int, double, unsigned short, char\ldots).\newline
Represented as a fixed-size vector of bytes.
\end{description}
Some more texts.
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

At last, let me explain different uses of the `enumerate`, `itemize` and `description` environments: (1) `enumerate` lists items with orders, and so is used for ordered lists; (2) `itemize` lists items without orders, and so is used for unordered lists; (3) `description` lists items with or without orders and with contents to explain the label words, and so so is used for descriptive lists.